# Duvida de como obter a resposta (Java)

Tags: java, web-service, aplicação-web, post, get

Amigos, é possível obter a resposta dessa requisição através de um `GET` ou `POST`? A pagina é:

http://nfe.sefaz.ba.gov.br/servicos/nfenc/Modulos/Geral/NFENC_consulta_chave_acesso.aspx

O que preciso é obter a pagina que é gerada quando preenche o campo chave de acesso e clica no botão consulta completa.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: como assim "obter" a página?

Comment: Preciso ler os dados que são gerados na página que aparece ao clicar no botão consulta completa. Os dados da nota fiscal

Comment: ai teríamos que saber que dados são esses e analisar o código fonte da pagina gerada para localizar em que elementos estão esses dados. Veja esse exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215468/pegar-valor-dentro-de-um-site-da-bovespa/215475#215475